# Проверка данных на уникальность

Tags: php, mysql

Как проверить, уникальны ли вводимые данные в таблицу бд mysql
с помощью php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$unique = true;
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='{$_GET['login']}'";
$r = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_affected_rows > 0) $unique = false
```

вот так я делаю

Comment: :) А дайте ссыль на эту страничку, я вам базу поломаю)

Comment: я на локальной машине експерементирую

Answer (score 2):

```
$field = 'login';
$value = $_GET['login'];
$unique = true;
$res = mysql_query('SELECT `'.$field.'` FROM mytable WHERE `'.$field.'`=\''.mysql_real_escape_string($value).'\' LIMIT 1;');
if (!!mysql_fetch_object($res))
  $unique = false;
```

Comment: А я всегда использовал [`mysql_num_rows()`][1] для проверки сколько строк вернул селект, т.е. вместо
    
     if (!!mysql_fetch_object($res))
         $unique = false;

Использовал

     if (mysql_num_rows($res))
         $unique = false;

Ничего не имею против фетча, просто еще один способ :)

[1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

Не надо проверять уникальность данных в базе с помощью пхп. Это просто не работает в многопользовательской среде. Используй уникальный индекс.

Comment: но это не избавляет от проверки всёравно

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($res))
    $unique = false;
```

либо уникальным индексом.

Answer (score 0):

хмм, а чем не вариант использовать ключи в самом MySQL ?